# javax.el.ELException: Property 'askQuestiοn' not found on type trainforjava.domain.Questiοn

Tags: jsf, el, propertynotfoundexception

My problem is the following. I've a list which i s well created, but I can't manage to display it on my web page.

Here is the pojo :

```
package trainforjava.domain;

public class Question {

    public int id;
    public String askedQuestion;
    public String proposal;

    public Question() {
        super();

    }


    public Question(int id, String askedQuestion, String proposal) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.askedQuestion = askedQuestion;
        this.proposal = proposal;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setAskedQuestion(String askedQuestion) {
        this.askedQuestion = askedQuestion;
    }

    public String getAskedQuestion() {
        return askedQuestion;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String askedQuestion) {
        this.askedQuestion = askedQuestion;
    }


    public String getProposal() {
        return proposal;
    }

    public void setProposal(String proposal) {
        this.proposal = proposal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [id=" + id + ", askedQuestion=" + askedQuestion + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is the managed bean :

```
package trainforjava.domain;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import trainforjava.util.QuestionCreator;

@ManagedBean
public class QuestionBean {

    public List<String> proposals;
    public List<Question> questions;
    public QuestionCreator creator = new QuestionCreator();

    public QuestionBean() {

        System.out.println("beforecreate");
        questions = creator.createQuestions();
        System.out.println(questions);
//      proposals = creator.createProposals(0);


    }

    public List<String> getProposals() {
        return proposals;
    }
    public void setProposals(List<String> proposals) {
        this.proposals = proposals;
    }
    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }



}
```

Here is the pojo creating from a properties file :

```
package trainforjava.util;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import trainforjava.domain.Question;


public class QuestionCreator {

List<Question> questions =new ArrayList<Question>();
    List<String> proposals = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<Question> createQuestions() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        System.out.println("createQuestions");

        try {

            input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/questions.properties");
            // load a properties file
            properties.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.size(); i++) {

                Question question = new Question();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("question-").append(i);
                String askedQuestion = properties.getProperty(sb.toString());
                question.setAskedQuestion(askedQuestion);
                question.setId(i);
                questions.add(question);

            }

        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return questions;

    }

    public List<String> createProposals(int key) {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        System.out.println("createProposals");
        try {

            input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/proposals.properties");
            // load a properties file
            properties.load(input);

            for(int i =0 ; i < proposals.size(); i++){

            int idQuestion = key;
            System.out.println("createProposals id" + idQuestion);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("proposal-").append(idQuestion).append("-").append(i);
            String proposal = properties.getProperty(sb.toString());
            proposals.add(proposal);
            System.out.println(proposals);

            }

        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return proposals;

    }

}
```

The console print me the list created, which name is "questions", but also print me a stacktrace :

```
beforecreate
createQuestions
[Question [id=0, askedQuestion=Quelle interface est implémentée par la Classe ArrayList ?], Question [id=1, askedQuestion=Quelle interface est implémentée par la Classe HashMap ?], Question [id=2, askedQuestion=Quelle interface est implémentée par la Classe Vector ?]]
août 23, 2016 2:29:19 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml: Property 'askQuestion' not found on type trainforjava.domain.Question
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:385)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:161)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

août 23, 2016 2:29:19 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: JSF1073 : javax.el.ELException intercepté durant le traitement de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=/index.xhtml: Property 'askQuestion' not found on type trainforjava.domain.Question
août 23, 2016 2:29:19 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: /index.xhtml: Property 'askQuestion' not found on type trainforjava.domain.Question
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml: Property 'askQuestion' not found on type trainforjava.domain.Question
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:385)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:161)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And then, the index.xhtml which is supposed to display this list :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    Question :
    <h:form>

        <h:dataTable value="#{questionBean.questions}" var="question">
            <h:column>
            #{question.askQuestion}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The property name is actually `askedQuestion`, and not `askQuestion`.

Comment: Thank you, I was probably too tired this day !